# adrianclay/xbrl composer

Tags: php, xbrl

I need to use adrianclay/xbrl composer to parse the XBRL and IXBRL files with PHP and this composer have a problem, can help me anyone to install and use this composer? or suggest me better composer for parse xbrl and ixbrl files in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Recommendations for libraries are off-topic.  If you want help with the one you _have_ found, perhaps include more details of what you've tried and the specifics of the problem you've encountered.

Comment: I have many financial account files with XBRL and IXBRL format  and i need to extract data from this files, I have problem to use this composer(adrianclay/xbrl) and i googled for this problem but i can't find any answer.